# how to bluimp jquery file upload on sailsjs

Tags: jquery, sails.js, blueimp

i was trying to follow the tutorial http://thejackalofjavascript.com/uploading-files-made-fun/ to do the bluimp jquery file upload on sailsjs, but don't know how it will work on sailsjs. I have tried to implement the code which doesn't work when posting the files to uploader.

```
   /**
 * UploadController
 *
 * @description :: Server-side logic for managing uploads
 * @help        :: See http://links.sailsjs.org/docs/controllers
 */
var path = require('path');
var appDir = path.dirname(require.main.filename);

var options = {
    tmpDir:   'C:/Users/ibrahim/Desktop/test/uploader/assets/images/tmp',
    uploadDir: 'C:/Users/ibrahim/Desktop/test/uploader/assets/images/files',
    uploadUrl:  'C:/Users/ibrahim/Desktop/test/uploader/uploaded/files/',
    maxPostSize: 11000000000, // 11 GB
    minFileSize:  1,
    maxFileSize:  10000000000, // 10 GB
    acceptFileTypes:  /.+/i,
    // Files not matched by this regular expression force a download dialog,
    // to prevent executing any scripts in the context of the service domain:
    inlineFileTypes:  /\.(gif|jpe?g|png)/i,
    imageTypes:  /\.(gif|jpe?g|png)/i,
    copyImgAsThumb : true, // required
    imageVersions :{
        maxWidth : 200,
        maxHeight : 200
    },
    accessControl: {
        allowOrigin: '*',
        allowMethods: 'OPTIONS, HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE',
        allowHeaders: 'Content-Type, Content-Range, Content-Disposition'
    },
    storage : {
        type : 'local'
    }
};

var uploader = require('blueimp-file-upload-expressjs')(options);

module.exports = {
    index: function(req, res, next){
        console.log(appDir);
        uploader.get(req, res, function (obj) {
            res.send(JSON.stringify(obj));
        });

    },

    'new': function(req, res, next){
        res.view();
    },

    create: function(req, res, next){

        uploader.post(req, res, function (obj) {
            res.send(JSON.stringify(obj));
        });

    }
};
```

//new.ejs

```
<h1>Test Drive Upload</h1>
<form action="/upload/create" method="post"
      enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide your code

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/q7idtq67b5skxzb/app.zip?dl=0

Comment: Code should be provided in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sails has built-in [Skipper](https://github.com/balderdashy/skipper) for file processing.

You can do it like this

```
req.file('[file field]').upload({
dirname: 'path to save file' //options
}, function(err, files)
{
  //callback once files are saved
});
```

Note: If you want to submit other fields along with a file, you have to ensure that other fields always come before files, otherwise req.body will be empty.

This will work

```
<input type='text' name='text' value='text'/>
<input type='file' name='file'/>
```

But skipper will not read 'text' from this one

```
<input type='file' name='file'/>
<input type='text' name='text' value='text'/>
```